# check the current backlog queue size

Tags: linux, networking

The sysctl `netdev_max_backlog` sets a limit to the maximum number of packets allowed in the kernel's backlog queue.

Is there a way to check the *current* queue size (i.e., how many packets are currently in the queue at a given time)?

Literally, the value of `queue->input_pkt_queue.qlen` from `net/core/dev.c:netif_rx()`:

```
  queue = &__get_cpu_var(softnet_data);

  __get_cpu_var(netdev_rx_stat).total++;
  if (queue->input_pkt_queue.qlen <= netdev_max_backlog) {
    if (queue->input_pkt_queue.qlen) {
enqueue:
      __skb_queue_tail(&queue->input_pkt_queue, skb);
      local_irq_restore(flags);
      return NET_RX_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the answer? Share if yes. I'm here with the same question.

Comment: nope, i never found out how :(

Answer (score 1):

```
probe kernel.statement("enqueue_to_backlog@net/core/dev.c:3536") {
    printf("probe enqueue_to_backlog on cpu: %d qlen: %d\n", $sd->cpu, $qlen + 1)
}
```

systemtap probe. Line number(3536) depends on kernel version, look for this line

```
if (qlen <= netdev_max_backlog && !skb_flow_limit(skb, qlen)) {
```